# Running Python scripts in Microsoft Power Automate Cloud

Tags: python, azure, http, automation, power-automate

I use Power Automate to collect responses from a Form and send emails based on the responses. The main objective is to automate decision-making using Python to approve or reject the form. I am aware that I can use Azure to run Python scripts, but I am unsure if I can return values from the script. Do you have any other suggestions?

I've tried without using Python, but the desitions are too complex for using the conditional blocks

Comment: Hi Valentino,  You can integrate Logic Apps with Power Automate and use it to execute Python scripts

Comment: Spinning up an Azure Function and calling it is your only way and yes, of course you can return values from that function. Alternatively, if you don’t want to do that and are happy using C# as an alternative, there’s an operation under the Advanced Data Operations connector that allows you to call C# directly from PowerAutomate.

Answer (score 1):

Power Automate online browser version does not have Python script connector, Thus you need to either run your python script in **`Azure Automation account`** or in **`Azure Functions`** and call it inside Power Automate flow.

But **`Power Automate Desktop`** version has a connector to run the python script, Refer below:-

***Sample Python script:-***

```py
import json

def process_form(data):
    if 'approval_reason' in data:
        response = {
            'approval_status': 'Approved',
            'reason': 'Form approved successfully!'
        }
    else:
        response = {
            'approval_status': 'Rejected',
            'reason': 'Form rejected due to missing approval reason.'
        }
    return response

# Example JSON data representing a form submission
form_data = {
    "form_id": "12345",
    "submission_date": "2024-01-04",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "approval_reason": "Valid reason for approval"
}

# Process the form data
result = process_form(form_data)

# Convert the result to JSON and print it
result_json = json.dumps(result, indent=2)
print(result_json)
```

**Power Automate Desktop:-**

[image]

And call this flow in your Power Automate browser version. By connecting your Power Automate Desktop Flow to Power Automate browser.

**Azure Automation:-**

You can create one Python Run book in Azure Automation service like below:-

[image]

And call this runbook inside your Power Automate Browser flow:-

[image]

As per the comments by @Skin you can also write an Azure Function code with Http Trigger to approve and reject your form, Then call this Function URL inside your power automate workflow:-

**Azure Functions:-**

I created one sample Azure Http Trigger Function and deployed it to Azure Function App:-

**Azure Functions HttpTrigger code:-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid JSON received", status_code=400)

    if 'approval_reason' in req_body:
        response = {
            'approval_status': 'Approved',
            'reason': 'Form approved successfully!'
        }
    else:
        response = {
            'approval_status': 'Rejected',
            'reason': 'Form rejected due to missing approval reason.'
        }
    
    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=str(response),
        status_code=200
    )
```

***Post body:-***

```json
{
    "form_id": "12345",
    "submission_date": "2024-01-04",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "approval_reason": "Valid reason for approval"
}
```

***Function app output:-***

[image]

**Call this Function URL in Power Automate like below:-**

[image]